# How to bypass mounting of all participation during booting

Tags: 14.04, boot, fstab

I have Installed Ubuntu on Virtual box & mounted shared folder from base machine. So during booting it hangs "Stopping Mount Network filesystems"

I want to keep that fstab entry because once system is booted then "mount -a" works ie fstab entry works! So how do i bay pass mounting at boot time ?

My /etc/fstab entry :

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=30603d6c-2cc1-4d8e-84cd-14121c031758 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
#UUID=c0e7dbcb-95b6-4dae-853e-b1c80548c7ca none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
Downloads-Base   /mnt/share   vboxsf  defaults   0  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `/etc/fstab` and remove the `auto` word from the entries for your network filesystems. This will break `mount -a` (which is documented as mounting all the `auto` entries), and you will have to `mount` the network filesystems manually (`mount /mountpoint`)

Comment: # cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=30603d6c-2cc1-4d8e-84cd-14121c031758 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
#UUID=c0e7dbcb-95b6-4dae-853e-b1c80548c7ca none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
Downloads-Base   /mnt/share   vboxsf  defaults   0  1

Comment: Above shows my fstab entries there is no auto, I have used defaults !

Comment: First, Edit your post to add formatted data, don't add it in a Comment. Second, the `fstab` you showed has NO network shares. What?

Answer (score 0):

I added "noauto" it worked for me !

New "/etc/fstab" entry :

```
Downloads-Base   /mnt/share   vboxsf  defaults,noauto   0  1
```